# Is removing superfluous information incorrect?

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits

I recently submitted [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1994497). I removed an introductory paragraph that had no real bearing on the answer. It was rejected by a ratio of 3:2.

I suppose my question is two-fold:

1. Are answers from companies acknowledging that something is a bug valid answers? In my opinion they should be.
2. Was removing that first paragraph correct or incorrect on my part?

Perhaps it looked too much like an audit? :) I say this as it was the first edit rejection made by petert out of 236 reviews. In any case, if the edit is correct and there are any willing >2k users, perhaps one of you could make the edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire post is "not an answer", as that introductory paragraph states.  The user knows that it should be a comment, not an answer, but he doesn't have enough reputation to comment yet.

The appropriate think to do is to flag the post as "not an answer" rather than editing it, because even after editing it it still isn't an answer.

Comment: I thought that acknowledging the problem and saying that it was being investigated would be an answer of sorts. It could potentially help future visitors having the same problem as now they would know it isn't their code at fault for example. The consensus seems to be that the answer is invalid though so I will have to change how I approach these answers in the future.

Comment: @Ren Saying, "we're looking into it" isn't an answer.  It's not even a particularly useful comment most of the time.  As for the end, that's just a guess.  If the person was asserting that it was the answer, then it could be an answer, but he's not, he's just thinking out load, which is a comment.  Comments can be helpful, sure, and this may end up being a helpful comment, but that doesn't change the fact that it's still a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind for the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest turn-offs for reviewers is large red(or green) boxes surrounding the text.

It's normally indicative of either **invalid edit** or **radical change**

Now I personally would have read it, and if the part below was actually an answer I might have approved it

but since it was not an answer, I might have realized that and rejected it  as too minor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to accept Servy's though as it was posted 33 seconds before yours.